# I downloaded and built quorum from the official git repo but I dont see the QOURUM OPTIONS

Tags: go-ethereum, ubuntu, quorum, linux

`git clone -b geth1.6 --single-branch` https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum.git
NAME:
   geth - the go-ethereum command line interface

Copyright 2013-2017 The go-ethereum Authors

```
USAGE:
   geth [options] command [command options] [arguments...]

VERSION:
   1.7.0-unstable-31f4acca

COMMANDS:
   account     Manage accounts
   attach      Start an interactive JavaScript environment (connect to node)
   bug         opens a window to report a bug on the geth repo
   console     Start an interactive JavaScript environment
   dump        Dump a specific block from storage
   dumpconfig  Show configuration values
   export      Export blockchain into file
   import      Import a blockchain file
   init        Bootstrap and initialize a new genesis block
   js          Execute the specified JavaScript files
   license     Display license information
   makecache   Generate ethash verification cache (for testing)
   makedag     Generate ethash mining DAG (for testing)
   monitor     Monitor and visualize node metrics
   removedb    Remove blockchain and state databases
   version     Print version numbers
   wallet      Manage Ethereum presale wallets
   help, h     Shows a list of commands or help for one command

ETHEREUM OPTIONS:
  --config value                      TOML configuration file
  --datadir "/home/ubuntu/.ethereum"  Data directory for the databases and keystore
  --keystore                          Directory for the keystore (default = inside the datadir)
  --nousb                             Disables monitoring for and managine USB hardware wallets
  --networkid value                   Network identifier (integer, 1=Frontier, 2=Morden (disused), 3=Ropsten, 4=Rinkeby) (default: 1)
  --testnet                           Ropsten network: pre-configured proof-of-work test network
  --rinkeby                           Rinkeby network: pre-configured proof-of-authority test network
  --dev                               Developer mode: pre-configured private network with several debugging flags
  --syncmode "fast"                   Blockchain sync mode ("fast", "full", or "light")
  --ethstats value                    Reporting URL of a ethstats service (nodename:secret@host:port)
  --identity value                    Custom node name
  --lightserv value                   Maximum percentage of time allowed for serving LES requests (0-90) (default: 0)
  --lightpeers value                  Maximum number of LES client peers (default: 20)
  --lightkdf                          Reduce key-derivation RAM & CPU usage at some expense of KDF strength

ETHASH OPTIONS:
  --ethash.cachedir                       Directory to store the ethash verification caches (default = inside the datadir)
  --ethash.cachesinmem value              Number of recent ethash caches to keep in memory (16MB each) (default: 2)
  --ethash.cachesondisk value             Number of recent ethash caches to keep on disk (16MB each) (default: 3)
  --ethash.dagdir "/home/ubuntu/.ethash"  Directory to store the ethash mining DAGs (default = inside home folder)
  --ethash.dagsinmem value                Number of recent ethash mining DAGs to keep in memory (1+GB each) (default: 1)
  --ethash.dagsondisk value               Number of recent ethash mining DAGs to keep on disk (1+GB each) (default: 2)

TRANSACTION POOL OPTIONS:
  --txpool.nolocals            Disables price exemptions for locally submitted transactions
  --txpool.journal value       Disk journal for local transaction to survive node restarts (default: "transactions.rlp")
  --txpool.rejournal value     Time interval to regenerate the local transaction journal (default: 1h0m0s)
  --txpool.pricelimit value    Minimum gas price limit to enforce for acceptance into the pool (default: 1)
  --txpool.pricebump value     Price bump percentage to replace an already existing transaction (default: 10)
  --txpool.accountslots value  Minimum number of executable transaction slots guaranteed per account (default: 16)
  --txpool.globalslots value   Maximum number of executable transaction slots for all accounts (default: 4096)
  --txpool.accountqueue value  Maximum number of non-executable transaction slots permitted per account (default: 64)
  --txpool.globalqueue value   Maximum number of non-executable transaction slots for all accounts (default: 1024)
  --txpool.lifetime value      Maximum amount of time non-executable transaction are queued (default: 3h0m0s)

PERFORMANCE TUNING OPTIONS:
  --cache value            Megabytes of memory allocated to internal caching (min 16MB / database forced) (default: 128)
  --trie-cache-gens value  Number of trie node generations to keep in memory (default: 120)

RAFT OPTIONS:
  --raft                    If enabled, uses Raft instead of Quorum Chain for consensus
  --raftblocktime value     Amount of time between raft block creations in milliseconds (default: 50)
  --raftjoinexisting value  The raft ID to assume when joining an pre-existing cluster (default: 0)

RAFT OPTIONS:
  --raft                    If enabled, uses Raft instead of Quorum Chain for consensus
  --raftblocktime value     Amount of time between raft block creations in milliseconds (default: 50)
  --raftjoinexisting value  The raft ID to assume when joining an pre-existing cluster (default: 0)
  --raftport value          The port to bind for the raft transport (default: 50400)

ACCOUNT OPTIONS:
  --unlock value    Comma separated list of accounts to unlock
  --password value  Password file to use for non-inteactive password input

API AND CONSOLE OPTIONS:
  --rpc                  Enable the HTTP-RPC server
  --rpcaddr value        HTTP-RPC server listening interface (default: "localhost")
  --rpcport value        HTTP-RPC server listening port (default: 8545)
  --rpcapi value         API's offered over the HTTP-RPC interface
  --ws                   Enable the WS-RPC server
  --wsaddr value         WS-RPC server listening interface (default: "localhost")
  --wsport value         WS-RPC server listening port (default: 8546)
  --wsapi value          API's offered over the WS-RPC interface
  --wsorigins value      Origins from which to accept websockets requests
  --ipcdisable           Disable the IPC-RPC server
  --ipcpath              Filename for IPC socket/pipe within the datadir (explicit paths escape it)
  --rpccorsdomain value  Comma separated list of domains from which to accept cross origin requests (browser enforced)
  --jspath loadScript    JavaScript root path for loadScript (default: ".")
  --exec value           Execute JavaScript statement
  --preload value        Comma separated list of JavaScript files to preload into the console

NETWORKING OPTIONS:
  --bootnodes value     Comma separated enode URLs for P2P discovery bootstrap (set v4+v5 instead for light servers)
  --bootnodesv4 value   Comma separated enode URLs for P2P v4 discovery bootstrap (light server, full nodes)
  --bootnodesv5 value   Comma separated enode URLs for P2P v5 discovery bootstrap (light server, light nodes)
  --port value          Network listening port (default: 30303)
  --maxpeers value      Maximum number of network peers (network disabled if set to 0) (default: 25)
  --maxpendpeers value  Maximum number of pending connection attempts (defaults used if set to 0) (default: 0)
  --nat value           NAT port mapping mechanism (any|none|upnp|pmp|extip:<IP>) (default: "any")
  --nodiscover          Disables the peer discovery mechanism (manual peer addition)
  --v5disc              Enables the experimental RLPx V5 (Topic Discovery) mechanism
  --netrestrict value   Restricts network communication to the given IP networks (CIDR masks)
  --nodekey value       P2P node key file
  --nodekeyhex value    P2P node key as hex (for testing)

MINER OPTIONS:
  --mine                    Enable mining
  --minerthreads value      Number of CPU threads to use for mining (default: 2)
  --etherbase value         Public address for block mining rewards (default = first account created) (default: "0")
  --targetgaslimit value    Target gas limit sets the artificial target gas floor for the blocks to mine (default: 4712388)
  --gasprice "18000000000"  Minimal gas price to accept for mining a transactions
  --extradata value         Block extra data set by the miner (default = client version)

GAS PRICE ORACLE OPTIONS:
  --gpoblocks value      Number of recent blocks to check for gas prices (default: 10)
  --gpopercentile value  Suggested gas price is the given percentile of a set of recent transaction gas prices (default: 50)

VIRTUAL MACHINE OPTIONS:
  --vmdebug  Record information useful for VM and contract debugging

LOGGING AND DEBUGGING OPTIONS:
  --metrics                 Enable metrics collection and reporting
  --fakepow                 Disables proof-of-work verification
  --nocompaction            Disables db compaction after import
  --verbosity value         Logging verbosity: 0=silent, 1=error, 2=warn, 3=info, 4=debug, 5=detail (default: 3)
  --vmodule value           Per-module verbosity: comma-separated list of <pattern>=<level> (e.g. eth/*=5,p2p=4)
  --backtrace value         Request a stack trace at a specific logging statement (e.g. "block.go:271")
  --debug                   Prepends log messages with call-site location (file and line number)
  --pprof                   Enable the pprof HTTP server
  --pprofaddr value         pprof HTTP server listening interface (default: "127.0.0.1")
  --pprofport value         pprof HTTP server listening port (default: 6060)
  --memprofilerate value    Turn on memory profiling with the given rate (default: 524288)
  --blockprofilerate value  Turn on block profiling with the given rate (default: 0)
  --cpuprofile value        Write CPU profile to the given file
  --trace value             Write execution trace to the given file

WHISPER (EXPERIMENTAL) OPTIONS:
  --shh                       Enable Whisper
  --shh.maxmessagesize value  Max message size accepted (default: 1048576)
  --shh.pow value             Minimum POW accepted (default: 0.2)

DEPRECATED OPTIONS:
  --fast   Enable fast syncing through state downloads
  --light  Enable light client mode

MISC OPTIONS:
  --emitcheckpoints  If enabled, emit specially formatted logging checkpoints
  --help, -h         show help
```

downloaded and built from here, I am not getting the --permissioned flag and Quorum Options when I do geth --help. I am sure getting the --raft flag though.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Found it in the new release branch "permissioned" https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum/branches/all

Also comes with Istanbul BFT.